# Upsert with Slick in Scala

Tags: scala, slick

We are using `Slick 3.2.1` in a *Scala project* to insert data on `MySql`.

The table where we are inserting data has an `auto-increment PK` and the `Upsert` operation was working as expected.

However, after creating a new index (a composite unique index on 2 columns other than the `PK` column), Upsert is working in a confusing way.

When inserting a new record that in theory would violate the unique index, `Upsert` is updating the existing record instead of trying to insert a new one.

Is this the expected behavior? I thought that Upsert would only rely on the existence of the `PK`.

Comment: If it is of any help, I have found, by chance, that upsert works correctly when creating the index on H2 with the syntax CREATE INDEX (although if the index is created with the syntax ALTER TABLE, upsert does not work as expected on H2 either)

Comment: By the way, what I meant in this post by Upsert is the Slick operation "insertOrUpdate"